# Is there a convenient way to represent x86 instructions in a struct or other language feature?

Tags: rust

Rust doesn't have a "bit" data type, however, x86 instructions have a "field" which is in size of bits. Instead of using bit-wise operations, is there any data structure that can be directly compiled to such "memory/byte alignment" required by x86 instruction set or any binary protocol?

```
OpCode 1or2 byte
Mod-R/M 0 or 1 byte
    Mod 7,6 bit
    Reg/OpCode 5,4,3 bit
    R/M 2,1,0 bit
SIB 0 or 1 byte
    SS 7,6
    Index 5,4,3
    Base 2,1,0
Displacement 0,1,2 or 4 byte
Immediate 0,1,2 or 4
```

Comment: Rust does have a 'bit' datatype, it's called "boolean". Your question is very unclear. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to read or write a binary format?

Comment: sorry , i don't know rust boolean is in size of one bit , my English is  rough too, i am trying to read or generate binary format , that' right.

Comment: could you talk more about the boolean type in rust ? capture the essence of rust.

Comment: Johnny I think what @WesleyWiser meant is not that a boolean in Rust is a one-eight of a byte long, but rather that it stores one bit of information (it's either true, or false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any data structure that can be directly compiled

No, there are no structures that correspond to this:

```
OpCode 1or2 byte
```

That is, you cannot have a struct that has a value that is **either** one or two bytes long. Structures have a fixed size at compile time.

Your main choices are:

1. Use pretty Rust features like enums and structs. This is likely to not match the bit pattern of the actual instructions.
2. Make something like `struct Instruction([u8; 4])` and implement methods that use bitwise operations. This will allow you to match the bit patterns.

Since you don't want to use bitwise operations and must match the bit representation, I do not believe your problem can currently be solved in the fashion you'd like.

Personally, I'd probably go the enum route and implement methods to parse the raw instructions from a type implementing `Read` and `Write` back to bytes.

---

It's also possible you are interested in *bitfields*, like this C++ example:

```
struct S {
    unsigned int b : 3;
};
```

There is no direct support for that in Rust, but a few crates appear to support macros to create them. Perhaps that would be useful.

Comment: yes, it is help full , by speak of fashion , i don't like the 'include<"FilesPath"> '(operating on the file system level)',and i just learned from there that C++ can do the bit-wise format declaratively , and i consider every declarative feature in HLL  is good thing,

Comment: This is a good answer. It's easier to work with an abstract representation (if you want a bit, represent it as one bit of information not size) and then serialise/deserialise to the physical format as needed.